# audio cd s not burning to mp3 format-burning to wav format in k3b and brasero using ubuntu 12.04.2

Tags: 12.04, mp3, burning, brasero, k3b

It started in ubuntu 13.04-I was doing what I usually do,I opened brasero to make an audio cd from a few mp3 audio files..When burned I noticed the files on cd were in wav format.I then tried k3b with the same result.At that point and because of several issues with 13.04 I formatted my hdd and dropped back to ubuntu 12.04.On 12.04 I tried brasero and k3b once again with same results.I know that when I used to burn cd s using brasero they were burned to cd in mp3 format not wave.Can anyone tell me a fix for this?I have restricted codecs installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong to fix.  The audio format used for audio CD, is the WAVE (.WAV) and AIFF (.AIF) formats.

So, for the highest possible fidelity on your audio CD, it is best to burn WAVE or AIFF files.

If you want to burn as MP3, then you may want to choose create a Data CD.